# Using Static variables in recursive functions to reduce the overhead

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, static

The utilisation of static variables recursive algorithms can help reduce the overhead by a large margin? Or it is neglijable?

For example, in a backtracking algorithm, having the solution vector as a static variable is going to make the algorithm better than having it as a parameter?

Or it is just a rule of thumb to never use static variables?

Comment: *"Or it is just a rule of thumb to never use static variables?"* Now that is certainly nonsense. For the main question: Probably depends on what you are doing. Write for clarity first, optimize later and don't guess about performance.

Comment: If you use a static variable for the solution vector, how will you reinitialise it for a subsequent call to the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use static variables, but it is not going to save you a lot.  Every time you make a recursive call, a [number of things have to go on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack): the return address, the parameters, all newly allocated variables for the function.  If you put in the variable as a parameter rather than a static, then you are allocating only one more value per recursive call.  This means that even in the worst case, it will less than double the memory.